# Unity WWW.texture working different on version 5.5 and 2017

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently we are developing an Image browser Using Unity on Android platform。

We use Unity 5.5 first and use WWW.texture function to load external images stored in sdcard， WWW.texture funtion work fine in Unity 5.5 and the Image is clear to show(Image size is 5000*10000).

Now we upgrade Unity to 2017.1.0f3, and we still use WWW.texture funtion to load Image, our code has not changed. But this time the image is not as clear as we build it on Unity 5.5.

My question is what the difference between 5.5 and 2017.1.0f3 on WWW.texture funtion ?

This question has confused me for a long time and I appreciate for your reply: )

[image: image on 2017][image]

Comment: Not really sure what you mean when you say "not as clear". Why not add a screenshot of the image that shows before and after the update? Also add your WWW code

Comment: You say your _code_ has not changed but there's a chance that whatever _components you're using to display the texture_ have changed.  Double-check your inspector settings on your display object(s).

Comment: check your import settings and mip mapping, filtering etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Example code in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html) changed this small bit:

```
WWW www = new WWW(url);
[...]
```

to this:

```
using (WWW www = new WWW(url)) {
[...]
}
```

Comment: This will only automate the call to `Dispose()` on the instance of the `WWW` object; it will do nothing to fix OP's issue with the clarity of the image being affected.

Comment: yes. I think the main reason is the WWW.texture funtion is changed from  version 5.5 to Unity 2017. But I don't know how Unity company change this.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2017.1 WWW is a wrapper on top of UnityWebRequest and it loads image into texture using this: https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.LoadImage.html

I find  that in Unity 5.5, the mipmap of texture generated by WWW is false, but in 2017, the mipmap is true.

I have manually convert the image into texture as the link said. But the texture's mipmap should set to be false.